# Android AutoCompleteTextView unexpected behaviour

Tags: android

I am using AutoCompleteTextView in my application but it works unexpectedly. AutoComplete list show the unwanted text from list which i am not looking for but when i selected this text and remove focus from autocomletetextview than it set the proper text to the autocompletetext field. The other problem is that i want to gain the id of the selected text in the autocompletetext field i am associating this id when i am populating a list in the custom adaptor for autocompletetextview.
Here is the code i am using.

```
autoComMarker = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.auto_rainfall_of_markaz_id);
autoComMarker.setThreshold(1);
CustomMarkazAdapter adapter = new CustomMarkazAdapter(getBaseContext(),     R.layout.custom_auto_com_listview, marqazList);
autoComMarker.setAdapter(adapter);


autoComMarker.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {
            autoComMarker.setTag(view.getTag());
            Log.e("Markaz list", ""+view.getTag());
        }
    });
```

Here is the code for CustomMarkazAdapter:

```
public class CustomMarkazAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Markaz>{

private ArrayList<Markaz> items;
private Context CurrentContext;
private Markaz CurrentItem;

public CustomMarkazAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Markaz> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    items =  objects;
    CurrentContext = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return convertView; //Can't extract item

   CurrentItem = (Markaz)items.get(position);    

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)CurrentContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_auto_com_listview, null);      
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_auto_com_text);

    text.setText(CurrentItem.getMarkazName());
    convertView.setTag(CurrentItem.getMarkazID());
    Log.e(CurrentItem.getMarkazName(),""+CurrentItem.getMarkazID());
    return convertView;
}
```

}

The markazID i am setting here is not that i am looking for, its sets the markaz id according to the autocompletelistview item position.which i am not needed i need the markaz id which i am passed with the markazList.
Please help me, any help whould be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
  autoComMarker.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) {
               Markaz items= adapter.getItem(position);
               //Now you can get items of Markaz from items.get...
            }
        });
```

Comment: Always welcome. Actually that fills your model `Markaz` from the List of model inside adapter that you created with `marqazList`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the `position` of selected item in the `listview`. Do this as below in `autoComMarker.setOnItemClickListener()`:

```
  Markaz items= adapter.getItem(position);
```